# AbstractTableModel and cell editor

Tags: java, swing, tablecelleditor, abstracttablemodel

The example i have found:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm
show how to create a JTable with specified column (button). It works properly, but the my problem is, that i need to use AbstractTableModel instead of DefaultTableModel (as at the example shows).

So i created my own TableModel, which extends AbstractTableModel:

`public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
//..

    }`

and replaced:

```
 DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
dm.setDataVector(new Object[][] { { "button 1", "foo" },
    { "button 2", "bar" } }, new Object[] { "Button", "String" });

JTable table = new JTable(dm);
```

for:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new TableModel());
```

And then nothing happens, when i will click button at some row. Any suggestions?

Comment: `that i need to use AbstractTableModel instead of DefaultTableModel` please why, is there special reason to restrict something, override whatever that is implemented as method directly in `DeafultTableModel`, `1.` here are bunch Q&A about How to wrote AbstracTableModel, `2.` click by mouse to AbstractTableModel tag under your question, `3.` search Java & Swing & JTable & AbstractTableModel, `4.` read Oracle tutorial how to use tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you override `AbstractTableModel.isCellEditable` method to return `true` for the column with the button otherwise the editor will not be triggered. This method by default returns `false`.

Also, make sure you override `getColumnName()` to return proper name since the sample that you linked tries to find a column with name "Button" to setup the editor.

You may find a [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) implementation by @camickr useful.

This demo model works OK with the editor and the renderer from the linked sample:

```
public class DemoTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return (columnIndex == 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return "Button";
        case 1:
            return "Value";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return "Button";
        case 1:
            return "Value";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: overriding AbstractTableModel.isCellEditable sloved my problem. Thanks for your time.